# Table not formatting properly in InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, formatting

I've got a linked (from excel) table that will not format correctly.

These are my settings. 
[image]

**Header** and **Table** have been formatted in cell options which are linked to Paragraph styles.

The only thing that is happening is the **Table** cell style is being applied to the whole table. Left, Right Column and header are not changing to **Header** cell style.

I am bringing in the table, linked and have tried with and without formatting.

It doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InDesign won't arbitrarily decide what is a header or footer row. Sure, it would make sense if InDesign merely chose the first row of every table as a header. But, there are times where no header is desired, or where multiple rows are needed as a header. You **must** specify the number of rows to use as a header (or footer).

`Table > Table Options  > Headers and Footers`

[image]

*Then* the number of rows you specify will have any paragraphs style configured in the `General` options applied to them.

<sub>CC2017 screenshot, but the method is the same in newer versions</sub>